# CDI injection in Quartz JobFactory logs warning "No valid EE environment for injection of.."

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, quartz-scheduler, payara

I'm using this approach to have CDI with Quartz in Java EE:

```
public class CdiJobFactory implements JobFactory {

    @Inject
    private BeanManager beanManager;

    @Override
    public Job newJob(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle, final Scheduler scheduler) throws SchedulerException {
        Class<? extends Job> jobClass = bundle.getJobDetail().getJobClass();
        Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(jobClass);
        if (beans.isEmpty()) {
            throw new SchedulerException("No job instance found for job class: " + jobClass.getName());
        }
        Bean<?> bean = beanManager.getBeans(jobClass).iterator().next();
        CreationalContext<?> ctx = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
        return (Job) beanManager.getReference(bean, jobClass, ctx);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but I'm getting this error message in the server.log for all the quartz jobs and all beans I inject into them (the message is not logged for EJB's injected into the quartz jobs): `[Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] No valid EE environment for injection of`. The jobs execute successfully, they don't throw an exception, but I'm worried about this error message. I've tried annotating the jobs with `@ApplicationScoped` or `@Dependent` and so on, but to no avail. I'm deploying on Payara Server 4.1.2.181 and using Java EE 7.

Comment: I posted the 'warning' in google and got https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/3155 Related?

Comment: This is clearly coming from paraya itself, not CDI/Weld, so you can try and look when this error is thrown in their codebase. Looks like it comes from [NonModuleInjectionServices](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/master/appserver/web/weld-integration/src/main/java/org/glassfish/weld/services/NonModuleInjectionServices.java). Looks like a bug for any beans that are accessed from another thread(s)?